# How to Sort IEnumerable List?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, ienumerable

I have the following list:

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars;
```

The `Car` object has a model and a year.  I want to sort this list by model and then year (within model).

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
var sortedCars = cars.OrderBy(c => c.Model).ThenBy(c => c.Year);
```